# Calculate average of numbers in a column using column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way of calculating the average of numbers in a column using the column's number. For example, I know that the average of numbers in column E can be obtained using the formula AVERAGE(E:E), but what if I need to use the column number (in this case 5) to calculate that average?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX()

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($1:$1048576,0,5))
```

Change the `5` to the column number of your choice.

The `0` returns the whole column

[image]