# INDEX/MATCH using column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use an INDEX/MATCH formula, but where the columns have to be referenced with numbers. For example, in the formula INDEX(E:E,MATCH(C2,F:F,0)), columns E and F have to be referenced with numbers (in this case 5 and 6, respectively).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: how was this questioned not answered by Scott Craner in your previous [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479627/calculate-average-of-numbers-in-a-column-using-column-number)

Comment: Or something like this `=INDEX(INDEX($1:$1048576,0,5),MATCH(C2,INDEX($1:$1048576,0,6),0))`?  Just change that 5 or 6 for the column numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use numbers to refer to columns in a 2 dimensional array in an INDEX Formula. Using 0 for the row number will cause the entire column to be returned.

This will refer to the 6th column in the range A:G, i.e. column F:

```
INDEX($A:$G,0,6)
```

Your entire formula is then:

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A:$G,0,5),MATCH(C2,INDEX($A:$G,0,6),0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the offset function to refer to a column that is a specified number of columns from another column.

This will refer to the column that is 5 columns to the right of column A:A, i.e. column F:

```
OFFSET($A:$A,0,5)
```

Your entire formula is then:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET($A:$A,0,4),MATCH(C2,OFFSET($A:$A,0,5),0))
```

Comment: offset is a volatile function.  ok in limited usage on a sheet.  non volatile Index the better route in my opinion.  Still an option though .